# Query to find duplicate rows in a table

Tags: t-sql

I am running the following query which is terribly inefficient and can take hours.  I am having SQL brain farts today and I do not know how to improve this query.  There are several nullable varchar fields, and I need to identify the duplicate rows (all columns containing identical values as another row)

```
select * from transactions x where exists (
  select Coalesce(ColA, ''),
         Coalesce(ColB, ''),
         Coalesce(ColC, '')
  from transactions y
  where Coalesce(x.ColA, '') = Coalesce(x.ColA, '') and
        Coalesce(x.ColB, '') = Coalesce(x.ColB, '') and
        Coalesce(x.ColC, '') = Coalesce(x.ColC, '')
  group by Coalesce(ColA, ''),
           Coalesce(ColB, ''),
           Coalesce(ColC, '')
  having count(*) > 1
)
```

Why does this take so long to run?  There has to be a better way.

Comment: remove `Coalesce` from WHERE clause they are unnecessary

Comment: Does your table have a uniqueid column? If so I would drop the grouping in the where exists and add x.uniqueid <> y.uniqueid. Also, for where exists you don't actually return values so i would just do a Select 1, or some other constant value. I would also be careful about your coalesce matching, the way it is currently written would consider '' and NULL to be a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a much faster way using a subquery join.  It ran in under 10 seconds

```
select * from transactions x
join (
  select Coalesce(ColA, ''),
         Coalesce(ColB, ''),
         Coalesce(ColC, '')
  from transactions
  group by Coalesce(ColA, ''),
           Coalesce(ColB, ''),
           Coalesce(ColC, '')
  having count(*) > 1
) dups on
dups.ColA = x.ColA and
dups.ColB = x.ColB and
dups.ColC = x.ColC
```

The important thing about this query is that **it returns both/all rows**, not just the duplicate(s)

Answer (score 3):

You could improve it by

1. removing unnecesssary checks
2. putting a composite index on `ColA`, `ColB` and `ColC`

What is unnecessary? It seems to be unnecessary to join the table with itself. Why don't you use a simple `GROUP BY`? You also don't need the `WHERE`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(ColA, '') AS ColA, 
       COALESCE(ColB, '') AS ColB,
       COALESCE(ColC, '') AS ColC,
       Count(*) As Cnt
FROM transactions t
GROUP BY COALESCE(ColA, ''), COALESCE(ColB, ''), COALESCE(ColC, '')
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

```
DECLARE @transactions TABLE (
      ColA      INT
    , ColB      INT
    , ColC      INT
    , ColD      INT
    , ColE      INT
    , ColF      INT
    )

DECLARE @Counter1       INT = 0

WHILE @Counter1 < 10000
    BEGIN
        SET @Counter1 += 1
        INSERT INTO @transactions
            SELECT    ROUND(RAND()*10,0)
                    , ROUND(RAND()*10,0)
                    , ROUND(RAND()*10,0)
                    , ROUND(RAND()*10,0)
                    , ROUND(RAND()*10,0)
                    , ROUND(RAND()*10,0)
    END

;WITH Dupe
    AS (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                (PARTITION BY ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, ColE, ColF
                ORDER BY ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, ColE, ColF) AS rn
            FROM @transactions
        )

SELECT * FROM Dupe WHERE rn > 1
```

You can use an ISNULL on anything where you need to compare a value that might be null. Note that most of this I've written is just to generate a useful data set. With 6 columns and 10,000 rows I got 42 identical rows in less than a second. No triples. Bumped it up to 100,000 rows and I got 3,489 duplicate rows, including some triples. Took 3 seconds.

Here's an example using text. This whole thing took 25 seconds on 100,000 records, although my timer shows that less than 4 of that was finding the duplicates, with the remainder being the table population.

```
    DECLARE @transactions2 TABLE (
      ColA      NVARCHAR(30)
    , ColB      NVARCHAR(30)
    , ColC      NVARCHAR(30)
    , ColD      NVARCHAR(30)
    , ColE      NVARCHAR(30)
    , ColF      NVARCHAR(30)
    )

    DECLARE @names TABLE (
      ID        INT IDENTITY
    , Name      NVARCHAR(30)
    )

DECLARE   @Counter2     INT = 0
        , @ColA         NVARCHAR(30)
        , @ColB         NVARCHAR(30)
        , @ColC         NVARCHAR(30)
        , @ColD         NVARCHAR(30)
        , @ColE         NVARCHAR(30)
        , @ColF         NVARCHAR(30)

INSERT INTO @names VALUES
      ('Anderson, Arthur')
    , ('Broberg, Bruce')
    , ('Chan, Charles')
    , ('Davidson, Darwin')
    , ('Eggert, Emily')
    , ('Fox, Francesca')
    , ('Garbo, Greta')
    , ('Hollande, Hortense')
    , ('Iguadolla, Ignacio')
    , ('Jackson, Jurimbo')
    , ('Katana, Ken')
    , ('Lawrence, Larry')
    , ('McDonald, Michael')
    , ('Nyugen, Nathan')
    , ('O''Dell, Oliver')
    , ('Peterson, Phillip')
    , ('Quigley, Quentin')
    , ('Ramallah, Rodolfo')
    , ('Smith, Samuel')
    , ('Turner, Theodore')
    , ('Uno, Umberto')
    , ('Victor, Victoria')
    , ('Wallace, William')
    , ('Xing, Xiopan')
    , ('Young, Yvette')
    , ('Zapata, Zorro')
    , (NULL)

WHILE @Counter2 < 100000
    BEGIN
        SET @Counter2 += 1
        SET @ColA = (SELECT Name FROM @names WHERE ID = ROUND(RAND()*27 +.5,0))
        SET @ColB = (SELECT Name FROM @names WHERE ID = ROUND(RAND()*27 +.5,0))
        SET @ColC = (SELECT Name FROM @names WHERE ID = ROUND(RAND()*27 +.5,0))
        SET @ColD = (SELECT Name FROM @names WHERE ID = ROUND(RAND()*27 +.5,0))
        SET @ColE = (SELECT Name FROM @names WHERE ID = ROUND(RAND()*27 +.5,0))
        SET @ColF = (SELECT Name FROM @names WHERE ID = ROUND(RAND()*27 +.5,0))

        INSERT INTO @transactions2
            SELECT @ColA, @ColB, @ColC, @ColD, @ColE, @ColD
    END
PRINT CAST(GETDATE() AS DateTime2 (3))
;WITH Dupe
    AS (
        SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                (PARTITION BY ISNULL(ColA,''), ISNULL(ColB,''), ISNULL(ColC,''), ISNULL(ColD,''), ISNULL(ColE,''), ISNULL(ColF,'')
                ORDER BY ISNULL(ColA,''), ISNULL(ColB,''), ISNULL(ColC,''), ISNULL(ColD,''), ISNULL(ColE,''), ISNULL(ColF,'')) AS rn
            FROM @transactions2
        )

SELECT * FROM Dupe WHERE rn > 1 ORDER BY rn
PRINT CAST(GETDATE() AS DateTime2 (3))
```

Answer (score -1):

If this is a one time job, and involves a huge number of rows, and not to be made as a View, then perhaps you'd opt to INSERT SELECT it into a table with UNIQUE index with IGNORE_DUP_KEY option.